# GL_ShapeDrawer include

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, bullet, bulletphysics

I am having a hard time trying to include the GL_ShapeDrawer into my project.
This is my first try at c++ and am having a bit of a hard time getting around. Also using Visual Studio 2013.
I am playing around with the bullet demos, more specifically the vehicle demo.

I have a c++ openGL project in which I have managed to include bullet physics and I have managed to recreate some of the demo into my own project world, but I have encountered an issue with GL_ShapeDrawer.
I don't know how to include this into the external dependencies in order to use the drawOpenGL method, as GL_ShapeDrawer is not part of any of the libs I have manage to include (BulletCollision, BulletDynamics, BulletSoftBody and LinearMath).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: _I don't know how to include this into the external dependencies in order to use the drawOpenGL method, as GL_ShapeDrawer is not part of any of the libs I have manage to include_? `GL_ShapeDrawer.cpp` is just a file included in the  bullet demos. So you should try to add this file to your Project (and the Header file too). Probably you're getting an error message then, that other dependencies from "Demos/OpenGL" are missing. If so, please post the specific error.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for replying and sorry for the lack of info. What I have done is started off a new opengl project and included the bullet library into my project following this method [here](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Creating_a_project_from_scratch). I am now going through the demos to accommodate with bullet and with c++. In some demos, they include this GL_ShapeDrawer. However, n my project this header file in not in the "External dependencies", therefore I cannot include it. I there a way of adding the whole OpenGL bullet demo as a library to my project?

Comment: hi guys. After having a look into this GL_ShapeDrawer, I realized I can actually reproduce it's functions. Therefore I don't need to include the actual file. Thanks for the reply and sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was able to reproduce the things I needed from the demo myself. Therefore there was no need to use the file.